# How to set a multi-choice field value in a sharepoint list using powershell?

Tags: 2013, list, powershell, choice-field

I have a sharepoint list and I want to set some value inside it. The multi-choice field is already defined and it is already pointing on data. I just want to pick one of the choices and set it in the field. I don't want to create new values and adding them inside.

```
    $weburl = "http://sdfsdfsdf"
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    $list=$web.GetList("/Lists/ListName")

    $choice = # what do i have to put here ?

    $newItem = $list.AddItem()
    $newItem["multiChoiceField"] = $choice
    $newItem.update()
```

Comment: have you had any luck on this, currently trying to figure out the same

Answer (score 2):

from [msdn](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Multi-Choice_Field):

```
$choicevalues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue;
$choicevalues.Add("Green");            
$choicevalues.Add("Blue");            
$i["multiplechoicefield"] = $l.Fields["multiplechoicefield"].ParseAndSetValue($i,$choicevalues);            
$i["multiplechoicefield"].ToString();            
$i["multiplechoicefield"] = $choicevalues;            
$i.Update();            
#-or-            
$l.Fields["multiplechoicefield"].ParseAndSetValue($i,$choicevalues);            
$i.Update();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have seen this piece of code and it didn't fixed my problem. Plus, as I said I don't want to create new values because they already exist.

Answer (score 0):

May have stumbled upon it, in Powershell, I have an actual array variable of values

```
$languages = Eng,Fr,Sp
```

I set my field to equal this array:

```
$NewItem["TestLanguages"] = $languages
```

Spent forever trying to do what was listed above as well, but this is working for me (and so simple too)

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine for me in SP2016 (the field already had some values selected and they were overwritten):

```
$valuesArr = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue; 
$valuesArr.Add("Choice Value 1");
$valuesArr.Add("Choice Value 3");
$item["SomeSPInternalFieldName"] = $valuesArr;
$item.SystemUpdate($false)
```